# Calculating the 'Tonal Center of a Musical Key

Tags: theory

Concerning the 'Tonal Center' and 'Parent Scale', it took quite a while for me to wrap my mind, around this concept. However, through continued effort, I have reached an understanding, and am able to apply this to 'Practical' use.
Thank you for your efforts.

Donn___

Comment: I thought 'Tonal Center' usually meant the same thing as *tonic* - in that usage, the tonal center of A major is A. E flat is a tritone interval away from A - it's the note 'furthest away' from A.  Maybe you could link to the lesson?

Comment: This makes no sense. If the tonal centre is A, then that's the key. Eb is a tritone away, as far across the circle of fifths as is possible. Eb has no relation to A at all...

Comment: Can you provide more context or a link to the lesson?  The statement quoted in your question does not seem to make any sense.

Comment: Please add a link here. I can't find anything quite like that on that site.

Comment: @DonnGoodside Welcome to the site! It would appear that you've been given some incorrect / misleading information. I've voted to close this particular question because it's a bit unclear exactly what you're asking. If you post a link / clarify your question, many people here would be happy to help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I found what he is talking about: http://www.justinguitar.com/en/SC-507-CalculatingPMS.php

Comment: @Dom - that may be. However, the OP's quote is erroneous.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure I found the lesson [that you cite from the site in your question](http://www.justinguitar.com/en/SC-507-CalculatingPMS.php). While the content isn't as misguided as initially stated from your question, it is very confusing and uses a lot of nonstandard terms to talk about modes like Parent Major Scale (PMS) and and uses the term "tonal center" wrong.  Purge the lesson from your mind and I'll explain what you need to know about modes.

### What you need to know about modes:

In music we have collections of notes we call scales and one of the most popular is the major mode. There are seven distinct notes in the major scale and if you started building the scale on a different note you would have a different scale that is refereed to as a mode. To demonstrate this let's look at all the modes that exist naturally in the standard C major scale as we start from different notes:

```
C Ionian        C   D   E   F   G   A   B   C
D Dorian        D   E   F   G   A   B   C   D
E Phrygian      E   F   G   A   B   C   D   E
F Lydian        F   G   A   B   C   D   E   F
G Mixolydian    G   A   B   C   D   E   F   G
A Aeolian       A   B   C   D   E   F   G   A
B Locrian       B   C   D   E   F   G   A   B
```

As you can see, they all contain the exact same notes and if we line them up, you can actually see how they relate.

```
C Ionian        C   D   E   F   G   A   B   C
D Dorian            D   E   F   G   A   B   C   D
E Phrygian              E   F   G   A   B   C   D   E
F Lydian                    F   G   A   B   C   D   E   F
G Mixolydian                    G   A   B   C   D   E   F   G
A Aeolian                           A   B   C   D   E   F   G   A
B Locrian                               B   C   D   E   F   G   A   B
```

### What the lesson got wrong:

As you can see, we have all the modes of the C major scale. What the author of the site call the "tonal centre" is really just the root of the original major scale or Ionian mode. What he calls the PMS are the roots of the mode. So what he wants you to do is always know where the major scale is like you would know the the E Phyghian mode's relative major/Ioanian mode is C, but please **don't use this terminology this way**. It's misguided at best and completely wrong at worse. The tonal center of the mode should be what note you start your mode on (like E Phrygian the tonal center should be E) and while you should know what other modes you have access to this scheme get's the whole idea reversed.

Comment: Other way around, Dom. He's using "PMS" (a most unfortunate acronym) to designate Parent Major Scale, e.g., C major for all the white key modes, and "tonal centre" to designate the modal finals. I concur that it is an unfortunate set of terms nonetheless. I personally think that connecting the modes to an Ionian parent is misleading at best, considering that, historically, Ionian was a latecomer to the fray.

Comment: @Patrx2 the diagrams are really screwy then.

Comment: agreed. They aren't wrong, but they are coming at it backwards to the way most people look at modes. Instead of calculating the modal final from the major mode's tonic, which is how most people do it, he's calculating where the major mode tonic falls relative to the modal final, so he'll say, for instance, that the "PMS" for Phrygian mode is a major sixth above the final (which is true). That's not a big help when what you want to know is how Phrygian mode actually relates to the tonic of the more familiar major mode - you have to invert the interval to figure out that out.

Answer (score 1):

Not having taken Justin's lesson, it seems like Justin is wrong. When people say "Tonal Center" it's just another way of saying Key. You say to me "what is the tonal center of D Major?" I say "D Major". Sometimes it is useful to say "Tonal Center" instead of Key, because it implies that the key is ambiguous but seems to be closest to being in "this key" where "this key" is the tonal center.

What you have described (A => Eb) is a tritone interval which is sometimes called the blues note. It can sound cool in the blues inside the minor pentatonic against a major blues key.

So against the Major blues in A, and Eb will sound like the ultimate bluesy sad note as played by someone really cool. I would also be playing the notes in the A minor pentatonic scale which is also magically bluesy against the A Major Blues.

Comment: Tonal Center is often the "key" but the tonal center of any given key can be changed by simply starting ending and focusing the song around a different note in the key which would change the mode from Ionian where the parent key would be the tonal center to one of the other modes.  Changing modes is a function of changing the tonal center of a given key.

Comment: To be fair to Justin, googling *"tonal centre" site:justinguitar.com* doesn't bring up any references to the tritone above the root...

Comment: @RockinCowboy I accept that a tonal center is not restricted to the major and minor keys but includes the modes as well. Sorry to not have explicitly included that. Thank you for your addition.

Comment: @topomorto Yep, I tried to make it clear that I did not bother to even try to look for the lesson.

Comment: @RockinCowboy /  understanding that 'Modes, can be in 'Series, or in, 'Parallel, clarifies the confusion. The 'Tonal Center' of any 'Key, can be played in the  Intervals of each Mode. /  i.e., 'playing 'Mixolydian' by intervals, beginning in the Root' of Bb.

Comment: @DonnGoodside It's good to see that you are still an active member of Music Stack Exchange.  Hopefully we will see more questions (or answers) from you in the future.